# Using Environment Variables as part of Spark Configuration in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, cluster-computing

I'm currently trying to use environment variables for my default Spark configuration in a Databricks Cluster. For example, we cane use {{secrets//}} to fetch a secret from the back-end into our Spark configuration (usually for key connectors), I'm trying to do the same using Environment Variables. Does anyone know if this is possible or how would it be possible?

Appreciate the help :)

I have tried using {{ENV_VAR_NAME}} expecting this would return the already declared value, but it's looking into the secrets, not the env variables so it's not fetching any result.